# Vector<class> object from the STD won't show completion outside header file

Tags: c++, autocomplete, codeblocks

**EDIT: Solution: redeclare "using namespacer std;" in the .cpp file!**

Am using Code::Blocks, and I can't get a vector object to show me it's available functions outside the header where I declare it!

I can't get the box showing me all the functions I can do upon the object.

I have this in my .h :

```
    vector<DrawObject> objects;
```

And in my .cpp (of the .h file), doing this doesn't show anything:

```
    objects.
```

If I do objects. on the .cpp, it'll show everything like it should.
It will work, and it's just a minor nuisance, but it would be handy to have.

Comment: Have you tried providing full namespace solution on the declaration? `std::vector<DrawObject>` I've seen dumber things from intellisense-type functionality. Worth a shot.

Comment: Are you _including_ the header file in your cpp?

Comment: Yes, both on the vector, and with the using namespace syntax.

Comment: Code completion for C++ is hard because the IDE essentially needs to compile the whole (potentially incomplete and erroneous) code. Before libclang this simply wasn’t possible for normal editors and as a consequence Code::Blocks only offers very rudimentary code completion.

Comment: Yeah, code::blocks is my first IDE I've used for c++, and I do agree the code completion is abit weaker... but only thing I can compare to is Eclipse's codecompletion, with Java, might not be a feasible thing to compare to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design and I suspect that there’s nothing you can do.

Code completion for C++ is hard because the IDE essentially needs to compile the whole (potentially incomplete and erroneous) code. C++ is hard to parse anyway, never mind having to take care about continuous background compilation of incomplete code.

As a consequence most IDEs (including Code::Blocks) don’t actually implement a full parser, just a very rudimentary subset and the code completion is pretty primitive.

This may change in the future because now there exists a powerful and fairly efficient solution called [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html) for this. But until Code::Blocks is patched to use it internally, this behaviour wil persist.

Comment: Found out a solution: redeclaring using namespace std; on my .cpp worked!

Comment: Accepted due to explanation plus interesting link